# Religiously sounding synonym of agility

Tags: single-word-requests

For a role playing project I would like to have attributes that are derived from religiously sounding words. I know this is fairly imprecise, so perhaps examples are good: instead of strength I use fortitude, instead of wits - prudence, and instead of empathy - charity. One word that eludes me is agility - there is no good word I can find for it. One idea I had is vigilance, but I am not sure if this is a very good match.

The question: is there a better synonym for agility that would fit the religious aesthetic?

Comment: Could you use Fleetness? Accommodation? Servility? Humbleness or Humility?

Comment: I don't think the examples you've given sound religious. Also, you know *fortitude* doesn't imply physical strength, right?

Comment: Fortitude and prudence are cardinal virtues. Charity is one of the seven Christian virtues. Yes, I know that fortitude doesn't imply physical strength.

Comment: @nnnnnn The reason Fortitude works in the RPG landscape is thanks for D&D3 fortitude saving throw.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that these words aren't ever used in a religious context, just that they don't sound inherently religious. They're used in secular contexts just as often.

Comment: Do you want a word for physical agility, mental agility, or a word that covers both?

Comment: @CJDennis Physical agility

Comment: Physical _and_ religious? Both at the same time? Are there other words that are 'X and religious'?

Comment: @Mitch As far as I know words have connotations. Charity has different connotations that say hand-out. Fortitude has different connotations than grit or balls. If you have a game with religious aesthetic and in the middle of an exorcism the GM would say "OK, roll for balls!" it evokes different atmosphere than "OK, roll for fortitude." I would imagine in literature you achieve similar things by choosing the right wording.

Comment: @gruszczy I'd have a hard time disputing your claim about connotations. My (thinly implied) point was that whatever the connotations of adjectives for physicality, I find it highly unlikely (but not impossible because you never know) that any would also have religious overtones. But anyway the only connection I could think would be in stories about Samson.

Comment: @Mitch I think the Old Testament might have more references. "Swift" seems to be used a lot "Saul and Jonathan were lovely and pleasant in their lives, and in their death they were not divided: they were swifter than eagles, they were stronger than lions." I am not a fan of swiftness though.

Comment: @gruszczy Neither 'swift' nor 'strong' have any religious connotations at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best word I can think of without breaking a sweat (which I am loath to do) is ***spirited***.

> The girl's spirited nature revealed her enthusiasm* for godly pursuits.

*[Late Latin enthūsiasmus, from Greek enthousiasmos, from enthousiazein, to be inspired by a god, from entheos, possessed : en-, in; see en-2 + theos, god; see dhēs- in Indo-European roots.]**

**I will not charge extra for this insight. Consider it a lagniappe!

Comment: This is not bad, I will use this for now! Thanks!

Comment: @gruszczy: You're welcome. Glad to be of help. Don

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *spritely* / *spriteliness* (alternative spellings of *sprightly* / *sprightliness*):

> #### Adjective
>
> [**sprightly**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sprightly) (*comparative* **sprightlier**, *superlative* **sprightliest**)
>
> 1. Animated, vivacious or gay; lively.
> 2. Full of life and vigor, especially with a light and springy step.
> 3. (*especially of an old person*) Energetic and in good health.

Since sprites might be found in an RPG setting I think the flavour of *spritely* works better than *sprightly*.

As a bonus, they're anagrams of *priestly* / *priestliness*!